# How to automatically download the last build from TFS online?

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, build-process

as part of the continues integration process we want to download the last build form TFS online in order to execute automated tests locally.

Do you know if there is a way to download it automatically?

In the TFS ODATA SDK looks that there is not a way to do that.
We are trying do it by coding, but deal with the **live authentication** is a problem and the **alternative credentials** do not seem an alternative to download the file once we have the URL path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the regular TFS .NET client object model in order to do that. I've posted info on using alternate credentials and some sample code at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx.

Comment: Great, but after have the connection what I have to do? Is there a function inside the TFS SDK that would let me download the builds? or is there a way to use this connection to use regular `httpConnections` and use something like `webClient.DownloadFileAsync`?

Comment: It gets checked into version control. You will need to use the VersionControlServer class, call the GetItems method, and then call the DownloadFile method on each Item.
GetItems(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138913(v=vs.110).aspx
DownloadFile(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138502.aspx

Comment: Let us see, but it does not seems that would be used to download the compiled build (or zip), it seems to download only the files inside the repository.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. Unfortunately did not work for us, I think it is because the code is in GIT repository, we tested with the another code repository and yes, we were able to navigate to the assemblies. Any other idea?

Comment: @MarcoMedrano: if your files are in a git repository, there is a tool available called `TFSDropDownloader` that can help.  http://officesharepointci.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/83449  Sorry this is a little rough around the edges at the moment, we're improving this in future releases!

Answer (score 0):

Normally TFS defines a drop folder which is normally a network share which may be further restricted with windows access control. Since the drop directory represents the latest successful build why not just copy it from there? Xcopy works fine.

For deployment to a web site for example an additional task would be defined that copies te build to a target directory

Comment: I think marco is talking about Team Foundation Service, not an on-site TFS Server.

Comment: Yes, Team Foundation Service (online) if would be that feature there would be great :)